# Test express API endpoints with mock data using JEST

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I' trying to test my Express API endpoints with Mockdata using JEST.

Below is my Express API endpoints which will return me the data.

**api-routes.ts**

```
// Get release notes
routes.get('/release-notes', (req, res) => {
  request.get({
    url: 'https://host.com/rest/api/content/search?cql=parent=209266565',
    json: true
  })
    .pipe(res);
});
export default routes;
```

Below is my test code for validation, whether my API is returning data.

Issue is, I'm not checking the API call, please help me to correct my code

**api-routes.test.ts**

```
describe('Test API', () => {
  test('It should retun data', () => {
    const releaseNotesMockData = {
      'results': [
        {
          'id': '206169942',
          'type': 'page',
          'status': 'current',
          'title': 'Release 2018-10-18 Full Flow CM00294965',
        }]
    };
    const response = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(releaseNotesMockData)
    expect(response).toBe(response);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should mock this function to prevent actually API end-point call(prevent request itself, because it will always be calling your API). When you mock your function, you can also mock return value in case of success or failure and compare that return value with those you pass for `toBe` or `toEqual`(consider toEqual to compare recursively all properties of object instances).

Then, I am not sure it is a valid test because you're passing result and expecting its result equals itself. Of cause it always passes the test.
If you want to actually check whether your function have been called, you can use `.toHaveBeenCalled()`.

Comment: I have a repo where I wrote tests for firebase functions. I hope it will at least a little help you.
https://github.com/yevheniiIvanise/jestjs-plus-firebase

Comment: @user9813762 was off by one letter on their link, but the code is helpful for understanding how tests like this one might be formatted in a series testing the same service. The link is [here](https://github.com/yevheniiivanisenko/jestjs-plus-firebase).